# MySQL. Если значение ячейки меньше или равно

Tags: mysql

Весь запрос написал, но в конце запнулся. Нужно, чтобы условие `WHERE` сработало, если `_regular_price` меньше или равно 50. Если отправляю так, то условие срабатывает без ошибок, но не работает. Получается `SET` срабатывает для всех, т.к. сравнение происходит со строкой, которая больше 50 по весу, а не по значению из ячейки.

```
WHERE
    wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' < 50
```

Comment: А что Вы собственно сравниваете с числом 50, а? надо-то сравнивать meta_value, а Вы сравниваете результат проверки `wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price'`, который меньше 50, ибо может быть или 0, или 1.

Comment: @Akina Спасибо. На основании вашего комментария, я увидел ошибку

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE
   wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND wp_postmeta.meta_key = '_regular_price' AND wp_postmeta.meta_value < 50`
```

Вот такое решение было правильным